# How to split concatenated column name into separate columns?

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

In order to perform an analysis, I have been provided with a column name which contains specific information about the product, market and distribution.

The structure of the dataset is as follows:

```py
Date     Product1|CBA|MKD  Product1|CPA|MKD     Product1|CBA|IHR    Product2|CBA|IHR
2018-11  12                 23                   0                   2
```

There are a lot of unique column combinations. What I would like to do is to get the following structure:

```py
Date      Product    Partner   Market      Quantity
2020-1    Product1   CBA       MKD         11
2020-1    Product1   CPA       MKD         22
2020-1    Product1   CBA       IHR         0
2020-1    Product2   CBA       IHR         1
```

So, I want to create 3 different columns and populate them with pasted values from the column name. The quantity column would obviously contain the value of the old concatenated column (that bit I know how to do), the issue is getting the first 3 columns.

I have tried to do this in pandas by matching strings but I am really stuck. I'd appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Do you have regularly-named columns or not? For example, your first column is named in the form `A|B|C|` with an extra pipe at the end, while the others are `A|B|C`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I'll edit. They are all regularly named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could use `pandas.melt`

```
df_ = df.melt(id_vars = 'Date', value_name = 'Quantity')
df_[['Product', 'Partner','Market']] = df_.variable.str.split('|', 
                                                             expand = True)\
                                                        .dropna(axis = 1) 
df_.pop('variable')
```

```py
df_
Out[67]: 
      Date  Quantity   Product Partner Market
0  2018-11        12  Product1     CBA    MKD
1  2018-11        23  Product1     CPA    MKD
2  2018-11         0  Product1     CBA    IHR
3  2018-11         2  Product2     CBA    IHR
```

Comment: This doesn't quite give the expected result.

Comment: I didn't add the `Date` column as I think it's not important, but I edited my answer to include that just in case.

Comment: That wasn't the only thing. But it looks better now! +1

Comment: The date I added myself before you edited ;) it is appreciated you edited in case someone else runs into the same issue 

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
st = df.set_index("Date").stack().reset_index(-1)
res = st["level_1"].str.split("|")
st[["Product","Partner","Market"]] = pd.DataFrame(res.tolist(), index=st.index)
df2 = st.drop("level_1", axis=1).rename({0:"Quantity"}, axis=1)

print(df2)
```

```
         Quantity   Product Partner Market
Date
2018-11        12  Product1     CBA    MKD
2018-11        23  Product1     CPA    MKD
2018-11         0  Product1     CBA    IHR
2018-11         2  Product2     CBA    IHR
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = df.melt(id_vars=["Date"],var_name="Product", 
    value_name="Val").dropna(how='any').sort_values('Date')
a['Partner'] = a['Product'].str.split("|").str[1]
a['Market'] = a['Product'].str.split("|").str[-1]
a['Product']= a['Product'].str.split("|").str[0]
```